# Join on existing aggregate query to pivot result without id

Tags: sql, sql-server

On a Sql-Server instance, I have three tables:

**ActionItem**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Fish |
| 2 | Gravy |
| 3 | Pants |

**ActionData**

| Id | ActionId | Group | Field | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 300 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | NULL |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 5 | NULL |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 6 | "Some Text" |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 50 |
| 8 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 60 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 70 |

**Costing**

| Id | ActionId | Break | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Normal | 11.3 |
| 2 | 1 | Sub | 54 |
| 3 | 1 | Premium | 0.4 |
| 4 | 3 | Normal | 22 |
| 5 | 3 | Premium | 0.67 |

I have a query that sums the cost for each `ActionItem`:

```
select
    ai.Id,
    ai.Name,
    sum(c.Cost)
from ActionItem ai
left join Costing c on ai.Id = c.ActionId 
group by
ai.Id,
ai.Name
```

Nice and straight-forward:

| Id | Name | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fish | 65.7 |
| 2 | Gravy | NULL |
| 3 | Pants | 22.67 |

I created a pivot too:

```
select * from
(select [ActionId], [Group], [Field], [Value] from ActionData) src
pivot (max([Value]) for [ActionId] in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) ppp
```

Which gets me data in the right format:

| Group | Field | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 50 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | 200 | 60 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 3 | 300 | 70 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 5 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 6 | "Some Text" | NULL | NULL | NULL |

But I cannot join these two queries together because that PIVOT doesn't contain the `ActionId` ... even though I use `Select * from` - how can I get the `ActionId` col to show on my pivoted data, so I can join it to the rest of my original query?

I could not get [sqlfiddle.com](https://sqlfiddle.com) to work for MS SQL SERVER today but here are create and inserts if anyone's interested:

```
CREATE TABLE ActionItem
    ([Id] int, [Name] varchar(5));
    
INSERT INTO ActionItem
    ([Id], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Fish'),
    (2, 'Gravy'),
    (3, 'Pants');

CREATE TABLE ActionData
    ([Id] int, [ActionId] int, [Group] int, [Field] int, [Value] varchar(11));
    
INSERT INTO ActionData
    ([Id], [ActionId], [Group], [Field], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1, '100'),
    (2, 1, 1, 2, '200'),
    (3, 1, 1, 3, '300'),
    (4, 1, 1, 4, NULL),
    (5, 1, 1, 5, NULL),
    (6, 1, 2, 6, '"Some Text"'),
    (7, 2, 1, 1, '50'),
    (8, 2, 1, 2, '60'),
    (9, 2, 1, 3, '70')
;

CREATE TABLE Costing (
  [Id] int,
  [ActionId] int,
  [Break] VARCHAR(9),
  [Cost] FLOAT);

INSERT INTO Costing
  ([Id], [ActionId], [Break], [Cost])
VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'Normal', '11.3'),
  ('2', '1', 'Sub', '54'),
  ('3', '1', 'Premium', '0.4'),
  ('4', '3', 'Normal', '22'),
  ('5', '3', 'Premium', '0.67');
```

Comment: *"because that PIVOT doesn't contain the ActionId"* It does, but they are the columns now. Column `[1]` is the `ActionID` `1`,  `[2]` is the `ActionID` `2`, etc.

Comment: Yup after all that, I am pivoting on the wrong column - I just needed `pivot (max([Value]) for [Field] in ([1],[2],[3],[4])` AAAAAAAAAAAARGGH

Comment: ha ha ha it'd be sad if it wasn't so funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what output you expect.
But here's an attempt to join the two queries in 1 pivot.

> ```
> select pvt.* 
> from
> (
>   select d.ActionId, ai.Name
>   --, d.[Group]
>   , cast(d.[Field] as varchar(30)) as [Col]
>   , try_cast(d.[Value] as float) as [Value]
>   from ActionData d
>   left join ActionItem ai on ai.Id = d.ActionId
>   where isnumeric(d.[Value]) = 1
>   
>   union all
>   
>   select c.ActionId, ai.Name
>   --, 1 as [Group]
>   , c.[Break] as [Col]
>   , sum(c.Cost) as TotalCost
>   from Costing c 
>   left join ActionItem ai
>     on ai.Id = c.ActionId 
>   group by c.ActionId, ai.Name, c.[Break]
> ) src
> pivot (
>   max([Value])
>   for [Col] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[Normal],[Premium],[Sub])
> ) pvt
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ActionId | Name  |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 | Normal | Premium |  Sub
> -------: | :---- | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | -----: | ------: | ---:
>        1 | Fish  |  100 |  200 |  300 | null |   11.3 |     0.4 |   54
>        2 | Gravy |   50 |   60 |   70 | null |   null |    null | null
>        3 | Pants | null | null | null | null |     22 |    0.67 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=72f21197b5648fe156bd068efa21b1e7)*

Comment: Actually I was happy with the sum of the cost part but I accepted because this has some good nuggets in it and does technically give me the right results for the 1,2,3,4 cols. Also thanks for introducing me to dbfiddle.uk